# Get SQL Server public x509 Certificate

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssl-certificate, database-connection, x509certificate

How can I get/inspect the certificate used on SQL Server to encrypt the connection?

I need to retrieve and inspect the certificate, and if possible do some custom validation

This code works for most things, except SQL Server it just times out

```
var sqlServer = "sqlserver-fqdn";
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.SendTimeout = 10000;
    client.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;

    await client.ConnectAsync(sqlServer, 1433).ConfigureAwait(false);

    using (var stream = client.GetStream())
    using (var sslStream = new SslStream(stream, false,
        (sender, certificate, chain, policyErrors) =>
            { /* do some validation */ }, null))
    {
        sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(sqlServer);
    }
}
```

Throws exception:

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
> ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Setting `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += CertificateCallBack;` has no effect, it's only used for http clients

Comment: Aside... in SSL/TLS-based protocols the X.509 certificate isn't used to encrypt the connection, it's only used to certify and identify the origin server. The actual encryption keys used for channel encryption are usually computed by the client and server through a Diffie-Hellman key exchange during connection establishment (or a similar process).

Comment: The MS-TDS protocol isn't initiated over an SSL/TLS connection like HTTPS is, it's more like SMTP with STARTTLS where the connection is initially plaintext and then upgraded to a secure channel afterwards. If you need to extract SQL Server's X.509 public key you'll need administrator access to the SQL Server's host so that you can export its public key. How you actually do this depends on whether it's a Windows host, a Linux host or a Docker container. On Windows you can locate the key used through SQL Server Configuration Manager via the properties of "Protocols for <InstanceName>".

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you for the refresher, I am trying to find a way to remotely figure out the cert used.  I tried looking into the ADO.NET API, but there doesn't seem to be a handler I can use to inspect the certificate